# Create grid around lat/lng with same spacing on the diagonal points using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, distance-matrix

As an example I have a lat/lng circled in red below. I want to create a grid of points using SQL Server at 50m intervals up to 200m from the centre point. But those points that are on a diagonal are at intervals greater than 50m (shown by the arrow in the bottom right of the picture) and I would like them to be at 50m intervals too.

I have used the example code below to create the grid and was wondering if there was a way to amend it to get what I need.

[image]

```
Declare @Lat  float = 51.500709
Declare @Lng  float = -0.124646
Declare @LatM float = 50
Declare @LngM float = 50

Select OldLat = @Lat
      ,OldLng = @Lng
      ,NewLat = @Lat + @LatM/111111
      ,NewLng = @Lng + @LngM/(111111 * cos(radians(@Lat)) )
```

Comment: What tool are you using to perform measurement, and using what algorithm?

Comment: I did this manually using the sql above. So I created a table in sql of the different point distances I wanted in metres from the centre point. So 50,50 | 50,100 etc and then applied those measurements as LatM and LngM in the calculation: ```NewLat = @Lat + @LatM/111111 ,NewLng = @Lng + @LngM/(111111 * cos(radians(@Lat)) )``` Thank you.

Comment: Clearly, diagonals can't possibly be 50m if the X and Y are each 50m (`sqrt(2500+2500) = 70.71`). The formula you are using isn't going to be accurate to meter precision, anyway.

Comment: That's my question how to work with the diagonals. It doesn't have to be spot on to the metre. I'm happy with the small margin for error here as its over a short distance. I'm not great at math sadly. I'm having a look at some trigonometry examples online to see if I can get something working, even if crude. Thanks again.

Comment: This is basic Cartesian trigonometry. The length of a diagonal will always be sqrt(2) times the sides of a square. Making points that are all of an equivalent distance would be constructed from hexagons, but since the coordinates are spheroidal, there will be error

Comment: Ok thanks, see if I can find anything that applies this in sql. Thanks again.